# How do I Invoke a REST API from Azure DevOps using Bearer Token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to use an Azure DevOps task to programatically assign a LUIS predict resource to a LUIS app, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription#assign-a-resource-to-an-app). In short, this involves

- Get an Azure Resource Manager token from this [website](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true).
- [Assign a LUIS azure accounts to an application](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515), using Bearer token from previous step.

I am able to execute these steps manually, but how to I do this from Azure DevOps?
I have tried to use a 'Invoke REST API' task from an agentless job, but don't see how I can retrieve and use the Bearer token.
Note the Bearer token expires.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: How did you give the token in the Invoke Rest API task?

Comment: I have created a generic service connection in DevOps without username/password, and assigned that to the Invoke REST API task.

Comment: I've tried to hard-code the token in the header as {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer <token>"...}, but this gives me "(500) Internal Server Error".

Comment: But even if this hardcoded token would work, what is the right way to obtain this token and pass it to the POST call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a **powershell task** in your  pipeline to do this from azure devops.

**Get an Azure Resource Manager token**: You can refer to below powershell scripts to get the token. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information about where to get client id and client secret. Please be noted that the **resource** here is "https://management.core.windows.net/"

```
$client_id = "{client id}"
$client_secret = "{client secret}"
$uri= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/token"

$Body = @{
        'resource'= "https://management.core.windows.net/"
        'client_id' = $client_id
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $client_secret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $uri
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$token = $response.access_token
```

After the you got the token you can pass it to the LUIS rest api. Below script is just for example.

```
$LuisBody = @{
        "azureSubscriptionId"= "{subscription_id}"
        "resourceGroup"= "{resource_group_name}"
        "accountName"= "{account_name}"
}

$Luisparams = @{
    Headers = @{ 
        Authorization = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token) # pass the token which got from above script
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = "{subscription key}"
        ContentType = "application/json"
        }

    Body = $LuisBody
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = "https://{endpoint}/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/azureaccounts"
}

 Invoke-RestMethod @Luisparams
```

There is another [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/) you might find helpful.

Update: 
GetAzure Resource Manager token with Azure CLI with below script:

`az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.core.windows.net/ | jq -r .accessToken`

Check official documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/healthcare-apis/get-healthcare-apis-access-token-cli) for an example.

Comment: Great solution! I obtained the client_id from Azure portal's App registration, and generated a secret for the client_secret. Only downside is that I have to mange an additional client secret, and I was wondering if this could be done simpler? My App/Service principal is already registered in DevOps as an "ARM Service connection". If I use "Azure CLI" powershell task, I can use this Service connection. Is it possible then to obtain the token via Azure AD (hence aviod clien_secret)?

Comment: You can try this Azure CLI `az account get-access-token --resource "https://management.core.windows.net/" | jq -r .accessToken` . I updated above answer.

Comment: I ended up with an Azure Powershell task, with similar token retrieval: `$context = Get-AzContext
$azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile;
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile);
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId).AccessToken;`, followed by `Invoke-RestMethod.