# How to schedule a uipath orchestrator job using azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Is there any way/package available in uipath to schedule the orchestrator job using azure pipeline?
I got the uipath Integration package but it only provides the package for create pack,deploy package, manage asset,job run  and testcase run..

I referred different forum to get something regarding my requirement,but no luck.

Comment: As of this time, I am afraid there isn't a built-in feature or extension that can do this. However, if you can do what you want from command line, you can try using  command line task, bash task or PowerShell task to do it in pipeline. If the scripts require local software, such as UiRobot.exe etc., you can try using a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to run the pipeline using software on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by using the Orchestrator API (specifically [Schedules Requests](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/schedules-requests)). You can then [call the API by using a PowerShell job in Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587253/how-do-i-invoke-a-rest-api-from-azure-devops-using-bearer-token).